# Forcing Spree Commerce to disabling SSL in production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, spree, production-environment

When I change my app (Spree Commerce) to production mode, the app is running fine, but when I want to go to **"/admin"** page the server throws me "This webpage is not available" in a chrome browser. Also, I don't know if this is normal, but when the server throws me the error, the server changes the url from

> **http**://localhost:3000/ to **https**://localhost/

Can anyone help? Do I have to do something to the admin and log-in pages for them to work properly? This is my first time developing with Rails.

As an example, these are the logs that are produced when I try to go to `http://localhost:3000/login`

```
I, [2014-06-19T17:09:17.368486 #4208]  INFO -- : Started GET "/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-19 17:09:17 -0500
I, [2014-06-19T17:09:17.531531 #4208]  INFO -- : Processing by Spree::UserSessionsController#new as HTML
I, [2014-06-19T17:09:17.697253 #4208]  INFO -- : Redirected to https://localhost/login
I, [2014-06-19T17:09:17.697444 #4208]  INFO -- : Filter chain halted as #<Proc:0x00000004f9a0c0@/home/angel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_controller/metal/force_ssl.rb:65> rendered or redirected
I, [2014-06-19T17:09:17.697662 #4208]  INFO -- : Completed 301 Moved Permanently in 166ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)`
```

Comment: Post your routes and your get request with the error.

Comment: Also check if you are using ssl in the production environment!

Comment: I have "# config.force_ssl = true" with the comment symbol and this are the logs when I try to enter `http://localhost:3000/login"` I'm going to edit my question above

Comment: My guess is that the environment production you are using is configured to use ssl, that's why the url is changing in localhost. You have to disable it. If the pasted ssl is from development it's ok, if it's from production how are you running the server? rails -s ENV -e production?

Comment: first I did `export RAILS_ENV=production` then I did the migrations for the production database. I change the line `config.force_ssl = true` to false in `production.rb` but the server is still redirecting me to https

Comment: Yes I'm running the server with `rails s -e production`

Comment: New answer with a solution!

Comment: Edit the post to include a more descriptive question like: how can I force disable spree ssl in production.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Install gem to avoid this problem:

https://github.com/spree/spree_auth_devise

Someone had this problem before:

[Spree: Turning off SSL redirects /admin back to site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11549901/spree-turning-off-ssl-redirects-admin-back-to-site)

Also:

I had the same issue
fixed this by adding:

Creating a file:

../config/initilizers/spree.rb

```
Spree.config do |config|
  config.allow_ssl_in_production = false #This line
end
```

Seems to work.

Comment: I have that gem already installed, it seems that Spree is forcing me the SSL option, but I don't know where to change that option.

Comment: What about the initializer I pasted?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set **`allow_ssl_in_development_and_test`** to **`false`** in spree initializer.

**initializers/spree.rb**

```
Spree.config do |config|
  #...
  config.allow_ssl_in_development_and_test = false
  #...
end
```

**Note:** SSL requirement is removed in `Spree 3.0` Check release note [here](http://guides.spreecommerce.org/release_notes/spree_3_0_0.html#other-gotchas)